# How to send an image by mail in the body?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send an email in which I want an image to be sent in the body, not that the image is attached, but the mail arrives to me without the image.

I'm embedding it in the traditional way as in an html template

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/mails/birthdays.jpg') }}" alt="">
```

But the mail arrives empty, how to make the image arrive?

I am using laravel

Comment: You will have to host the image and add a direct url in your email template.

Comment: Are you sending and HTML email?

Comment: @Jerodev 
I already tried doing that but also the image does not arrive

Comment: @nforced 
I send it using a laravel blade template

Comment: The code you have shown is not "embedding" - you are simply referencing the image on your server.  If you want to embed an image - ie encode it and send it as data along with the rest of the email content - [the Laravel docs describe how to do that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#inline-attachments).

Comment: @Don'tPanic 
Thanks brother with that solve it

Answer (score 0):

either host it somewhere or embed it by encoding it in base64

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64IMGCONTENTHERE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the full path

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode(file_get_contents(resource_path('img/mails/birthdays.jpg')))}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(PATH_TO_IMAGE) }}" alt="">
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? What is `$message`?